# Why Sitecore RTE Field removing body section?

Tags: sitecore-client, richtext-editor

When I am trying to insert body tag in `RTE`, then RTE is removing once clicking on Accept (save) button. I am not surprised but wanted to know what else removed by default in Sitecore.

Like when I am trying to put complete HTML body with doctype as

`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">`

`<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`

then neither I am able to edit nor save the content in RTE.
This issue is coming on one instance, and not coming on another instance of the same solution.

**My question here is:**

What are the other things which by default Sitecore removed, Are they configurable?

Is it good practice to put complete HTML with doctype in Sitecore RTE field?

I checked and found that Rick text field has `Is XHTML` applied, Do we have any relation with this?

Comment: No, why would you do that. This is very bad practice. The RichText field is for Rich Text, not to be used as an HTML editor, and certainly not to put the whole HTML body with doc type. Its for content.

Comment: No sure about your first question but I can say that it's not a good practice to put complete HTML with doc-type in RTE field.

Comment: Another comment here, you have asked 3 questions in a single post. You should limit to a single question per post please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It's not a good practice to put entire HTML document into RTE field.**

However, if do that, then Sitecore treats your text as valid Html and indeed the mentioned snippet will result in an empty page because there is no actual content. For example, the following HTML shows "My first paragraph." in RTE field:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><body>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

There is a number of RTE configuration options defined in Sitecore.config. The summary is below. More information is in Sitecore.config.

- `HtmlEditor.DefaultConfigurationType`

  Specifies the type responsible for setting up the rich text editor.
- `HtmlEditor.DefaultProfile`

  Path to the default html editor profile.
- `HtmlEditor.LineBreak`

  Specifies the tag that the HTML editor inserts on Enter. Values can be "br", "div" and "p".
- `HtmlEditor.RemoveScripts`

  If true, the rich text editor removes script tags and inline scripts from RTE field values before saving. Setting the value to true reduces the potential for cross-site scripting and other script-related issues. Default value: true
- `HtmlEditor.SupportWebControls`

  Indicates if the Html Editor supports web controls. If true, Web Controls are shown as yellow boxes. Default value: true
- `HtmlEditor.ValidatorServiceUrl`

  Specifies the url that validates XHtml.

Comment: Feel free to edit the answer or leave a comment instead of downvoting.